# Linux php codeigniter permissions 403 error

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, permissions

I am trying to get php5 and codeigniter to work on arch linux. now all the directory permissions are messed up . When I get the list of permissions

```
    ls -l

drwxrwxrwx 16 ytsejam users 4096 Jul 26 23:45 public_html
```

my test.php was working but now I constantly get the :

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. Error 403.
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Some extra information would be helpful.  Like what web server are you using, and what's inside `public_html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command on the directory the folders are in, and then (after reading about file permissions for web servers), continue gradually restricting the permissions until you can confirm everything works. Do ***NOT*** leave your permissions as 777.

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/your/public_html
```

If it doesn't work after that command, then something more is wrong.